# JSONDecodeError occurs sometimes and sometimes not

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch the "Underlying Index" value from https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY

```py
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY"

bnf_text = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36"})

underlying_value = json.loads(bnf_text.text)

underlying_value = underlying_value['records']['underlyingValue']

print(underlying_value)
```

Sometimes, it fetches the value. In other cases, it gives me:

> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

How can I avoid this error from occurring?

Comment: This means that the API is returning an empty response. You should check whether `bnf_text.text` is empty before trying to load it.

Comment: Also, search for the error message. There are literally hundreds of similar questions here!

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case, someone made a library to do exactly what you're trying to do.

https://nsetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html

`pip install nsetools`

```
from nsetools import Nse
nse = Nse()
quote = nse.get_index_quote("NIFTY BANK")
print(quote['lastPrice'])
```

Output:

```
36088.15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update JSON.loads with the below code.

```
underlying_value = json.loads(bnf_text.text or '{}')
```

It returns an empty dictionary instead of None. You can also replace the empty dict as per your need.